# Как избежать повтора?

Tags: стилистика

Предложение вот такого типа: "Тем более, **что** то, **что** он красавец, и так видно". Тут меня напрягает повтор "что". Можно и нужно ли как-то его избегать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, повторы избегать нужно, если они не являются стилистическим приемом. В вашем случае возможный вариант замены: "*Тем более и так видно, что он красавец*" или "*Тем более что и так видно: он красавец*". (*Тем более что* - сложный союз, запятая ставится перед ним; допустима постановка запятой перед *что* при интонационном выделении).

Answer (score 0):

Еще такой вариант: *Тем более то, что он красавец, и так видно.*

Comment: Возможно, чтобы сделать логическое ударение. Но это всего лишь вариант.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам первое "что"?
Оно тут даже по грамматике не очень лезет.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Валентин](/users/981/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD)](/users/981/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD):

> Главный вопрос состоял в том, как избежать повторов.

В вопросе "повтор**а**" (ед. ч.), т. е. он относится к данному конкретному случаю. 
Читайте внимательнее. 
И ещё я Вас плохо понимаю:

> Я говорил ещё и про строение
> предложений. olsa и inna
> перефразировали, чтобы не было лишних
> "что", а я про это и говорю.

Вы же призывали

> узнавать как можно больше синонимов.

Что ж у Вас глагол "говорить" повторяется? Да и с точки зрения "строения предложений", Ваше высказывание далеко не безупречно.

Answer (score -2):

Главный вопрос состоял в том, как избежать повторов. Отвечаю: узнавать как можно больше синонимов и учиться строить предложение так, чтобы не появлялись такие вопросы.

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё читать перед тем как писать.
Вы много знаете синонимом слову "что"?

Comment: Я говорил ещё и про строение предложений. olsa и _inna_ перефразировали, чтобы не было лишних "что", а я про это и говорю.